# Mock a physical web server while junit test running

Tags: java, testing, appium, stubby4j

I am searching for a simple framework which is able to mock JSON responses for specific URLs and therefore starts an in-memory server. E.g. the framework could start a node.js server or similar.

I need a physical server since the unit tests are running against an external application (using selenium) and this application has a dependency to a JSON interface. The application itself is iPhone-App running inside of simulator and communicates to a REST interface.

Is there an existing framework for this or what would be the best approach given that I *need* to execute the tests with jUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a stub server, given that you can configure the JSON URL in your client application.

Have a look for example at:

- https://github.com/dreamhead/moco
- https://stubby4j.com

You can start these in your maven build during the pre-integrationtest phase and shut them down in post-integration test phase.

Comment: This looks perfect. Is there a possibility to configure the JSON response dynamically i.e. per code? I just had a short look and couldn't figure it out immediately.

Comment: You can script the responses, for example for Moco have a look at the API: https://github.com/dreamhead/moco/blob/master/moco-doc/apis.md - Of course you would not put much logic in there or you risk to re-write your services.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. You can configure dynamic JSON responses. Check the https://stubby4j.com/docs/http_endpoint_configuration_howto.html#dynamic-token-replacement-in-stubbed-response

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm package [stubby-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stubby-db). What you need to do is;

1. Install : `npm install stubby-db -g`
2. [Mapping](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB#mappings) : Create a request response mapping which is quite easy. Specify the path of response file having JSON response.
3. Run the stub server: `stubbydb`

That's all. However since you just want to run it for your unit tests only which doesn't require much performance, you can also use [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/). It starts internally, and you never feel like you are running an external application.